# Equality of conditional probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Suppose $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent random variables. Prove that $P(\xi+\eta\leq x|\eta) = \Phi(\eta)$, where $\Phi(y) = P(\xi\leq x-y)$. I tried to express both of them into integrals but I don't see why they are equal.

Comment: Note that $a+b \leq c \implies a \leq c-b$.  It might help to, instead, calculate $P[X+Y\leq x | Y=y]$, assuming $X, Y$ are independent.

Comment: @Michael I don't  understand how to use the definition of independence here. I transferred the conditional probability into the form of conditional expectation and tried to prove the right hand side corresponds with the conditional expectation of $1_{{\xi+\eta\leq x}}$. Then how should I use the independence?

Comment: So are you trying to formally use the measure theory definition of $E[X|Y]$, or are you allowed to compute $E[X|Y=y]$?

Comment: @Michael Yes, I am trying to prove this equality with the measure theory definition.

Comment: Do you see the intuition for the more basic calculation of $P[X+Y\leq x|Y=y]$, and where independence is used?

Comment: @Michael Are you referring to calculation like this? $P[X+Y\leq x|Y=y]=P[{X+Y\leq x}\cap{Y=y}]/P[Y=y] = P[X\leq x-y]P[Y=y]/P[Y=y]$

Comment: Kind of.  I was referring to $P[X+Y\leq x|Y=y] = P[X\leq x-y|Y=y] = P[X\leq x-y]$ by independence.  The way you proved it is good if you assume $P[Y=y]>0$.  I suppose the way I was indicating above really uses measure theory in general.  Do you have "tower properties" (iterated expectations) that you are allowed to use?

Comment: @Michael Yes, your method indeed used the measure theory. Tower properties are welcomed but I don't see now how to apply them.

Comment: So I think you want to prove that if $X,Y$ independent then  $E[R(Y)\phi(Y)] = E[R(Y)1_{\{X+Y\leq x\}}]$ for all measurable functions $R$, is that correct? Or are you using some other definition/notation like $\int_A dP$?

Comment: @Michael I want to prove $E[1_A\Phi(Y)]=E[1_A1_{\{X+Y\leq x\}}]$ for all $A\in \sigma(Y)$. But I guess what you mentioned is an equivalent definition. I will check about that later.

Comment: There is likely a slick "theorem-type" method, but a brute force way might be to fix $\epsilon>0$ and write $1_A = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 1_A 1_{\{Y \in [k\epsilon, (k+1)\epsilon)\}}$ and then use the basic probabilities as in your "are you referring to" comment...

Comment: @Michael Could you please show me or give some hint of the "theorem-type" method? I really prefer to see such a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant theorems here would be Fubini-Tonelli and perhaps 
$$\int_x\int_y h(x,y)dF_X(x)dF_Y(y) = \int_x \int_y h(x,y)dF_{XY}(x,y)$$ 
for $X,Y$ independent.  So you can define $\phi(y) = P[X+y\leq z]$ and then 
$$ E[1_A \phi(Y)] = \int_y 1_A(y) \phi(y) dF_Y(y) = \int_y 1_A(y) \left[ \int_x 1_{x+y\leq z} dF_X(x)\right]dF_Y(y) $$

(I kind of like the $\epsilon>0$ approach though, in my earlier comment.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is elegant and I learn a new way of using the independence.